# jqGrid: Search Box: How to hide the search popup programmatically

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using the jqGrid plugin along with its 'advanced search' feature. Is there a way to programmatically show/hide the search popup? I'd like to hide the popup, if it's currently being displayed, based upon a user action elsewhere on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a jqGrid with `id="list"` then the "Advanced Search" dialog will have `id="fbox_list"`
(it will be build from the "fbox_" prefix and the grid's id). So, to hide the dialog it should be enough to use:

```
$("#fbox_list").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks. That works however, the 'mask overlay' that's on the main grid remains enabled, even after the search popup has been hidden. I can probably remove the overlay using Firebug and using similar tactic, but was wondering if there is a published way to do it. thanks.

Comment: @Jack Dorsey: You can hide the overlay with `$(".jqgrid-overlay").hide();` or `$("#lui_list").hide();` where the id="lui_list" will be constructed from the "lui_" prefix an "list": the id of the `<table>` element of the jqGrid.

Comment: @Jack Dorsey: By the way it you don't like the mask overlay you can use search option 'overlay:false', then the overlay will not seen at all.